# TableSorter - Remove unsorted icon from "tablesorter-noSort" columns

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

The `Actions` column has `tablesorter-noSort` class applied to it, i.e. it's sorting is disabled. How do I make it so that the `black-unsorted.gif` icon is not displayed in the `Actions` column header?

[image]

The CSS:

```html
<style>
  .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url({% static "tablesorter-master/css/images/black-asc.gif" %});
  }
  .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url({% static "tablesorter-master/css/images/black-desc.gif" %});
  }
  .tablesorter-headerUnSorted {
    background-image: url({% static "tablesorter-master/css/images/black-unsorted.gif" %});
  }
  .header, .tablesorter-header {
    background-color: #99bfe6;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
    padding: 4px 20px 4px 4px;
    white-space: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

The table header HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered tablesorter" id="myTable">
    <thead class="text-center">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Created</th>
            <th scope="col">Updated</th>
            <th scope="col" class="tablesorter-noSort">Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Comment: Try to add a new CSS rule `.tablesorter .tablesorter-noSort { background-image: none; }`

Comment: @alekskorovin, so that's all it took huh... Thanks!